# Making this.id equal to doc.id

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I want to make this.id equal to doc.id or the cont id from the previous function instead of the hardwired value I have in there.

I'm not sure on the correct syntax to get this done.

```
  addToCart(){
    this.db.firestore.collection('products')
    .where('tagid','==', "049a1092285e80")
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
              const id = doc.id;
              //const data = doc.data;

                  console.log("debug 1  ",doc.id); // id of doc
                  console.log("debug 2  ", doc.data()); // data of doc
                  console.log("debug 3", id);
                  //return {id};
            }) // end of for each

            // want to make this.id = doc.id 
            this.id = "KCSx3JPeoerFmeH5zW7R";
                  this.productService.getOneProduct(this.id).subscribe(res => {
                  this.product = res;
                  this.product.id = this.id;
                  this.amount = this.cartService.getItemCount(this.id);
                  console.log('tag id', this.product.tagid);

                  this.cartService.addProduct(this.product);
                });
     });
  }
```

Comment: you have multiple documents that you are looping through with your forEach, which doc.id are you trying to set to this.id? The last one? The first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good day!

Just use the arrow function to save context and modify `id` property:

```
querySnapshot.forEach(doc => { this.id = doc.id; })
```

Comment: This is it. Thanks a million! much appreciated

Comment: @cononor96, Not at all) Mark my answer as a solution. Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just wanting to get the last `doc.id` that was iterated on, change your `const` variable to a `let` and move it outside of your `.forEach` `function`

```
  addToCart(){
    this.db.firestore.collection('products')
    .where('tagid','==', "049a1092285e80")
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
            let id = null;
            querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
              id = doc.id;

                  console.log("debug 1  ",doc.id); // id of doc
                  console.log("debug 2  ", doc.data()); // data of doc
                  console.log("debug 3", id);
                  //return {id};
            }) // end of for each

            // want to make this.id = doc.id 
            this.id = "KCSx3JPeoerFmeH5zW7R"; // or id
                  this.productService.getOneProduct(this.id).subscribe(res => {
                  this.product = res;
                  this.product.id = this.id;
                  this.amount = this.cartService.getItemCount(this.id);
                  console.log('tag id', this.product.tagid);

                  this.cartService.addProduct(this.product);
                });
     });
  }
```

Another option would be to just set `this.id` directly in your `.forEach`. However, you would need to convert your `function` within your `.forEach` to use an arrow function instead so you have the right `this`

```
  addToCart(){
    this.db.firestore.collection('products')
    .where('tagid','==', "049a1092285e80")
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => { // change to arrow
              this.id = doc.id;

                  console.log("debug 1  ",doc.id); // id of doc
                  console.log("debug 2  ", doc.data()); // data of doc
                  console.log("debug 3", id);
                  //return {id};
            }) // end of for each

                  this.productService.getOneProduct(this.id).subscribe(res => {
                  this.product = res;
                  this.product.id = this.id;
                  this.amount = this.cartService.getItemCount(this.id);
                  console.log('tag id', this.product.tagid);

                  this.cartService.addProduct(this.product);
                });
     });
  }
```